# Fill ViewData on Every Action but not on renderaction

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing, viewdata

I have a `viewData` that is required to be available on each page. If I fill this `ViewData` using `onActionExecuting`. It gets filled for every action even for actionresult of partial pages. I want ViewData to be get filled only once for each Page Load. 
Any suggestion

Answer (score 2):

You could use the OnActionExecuting event and test if the result returned b the view is a normal view or a partial view and based on that decide whether or not to add the information to ViewData:

```
public class MyActionFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.Result is ViewResult)
        {
            filterContext.Controller.ViewData["foo"] = "bar";
        }
    }
}
```

Another possibility to have some common data available to all views is to externalize it in a separate child action and use the [Html.Action helper](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/11/18/aspnetmvc2-render-action.aspx) to include it in your layout for example.

Comment: I am getting null in filterContext.Result. I was thinking of second approach also let me see if it will do the trick

Comment: @Tassadaque, what is null? `filterContext`? Or `filterContext.Result`? Or something else? How does your exact code look like? What about the controller action?

Comment: filterContext.Result is null in filtercontext i get ?filterContext
{System.Web.Mvc.ActionExecutingContext}
    base {System.Web.Mvc.ControllerContext}: {System.Web.Mvc.ActionExecutingContext}
    ActionDescriptor: {System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor}
    ActionParameters: Count = 7
    Result: null

Comment: I am just adding it in one of my customer actionfilterattribute's code which is public class RequiresAuthenticationAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {

        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)

Comment: @Tassadaque, of course that filterContext.Result will be null inside `OnActionExecuting`. This event is executed **before** the action runs so you cannot expect to have a result yet. You should use the `OnActionExecuted` event instead.

Comment: Oh thanks missed that. It is working now. but In my application renderaction is returning View() instead of PartialView(). So I think condition not get executed. Currently I have approach in which I use TempData with renderaction and using this at the moment but surely dig into it more.  thanks